# Error al sincronizar proyecto android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hoy he abierto mi proyecto de android studio y me he encontrado errores por todo el código y el siguiente mensaje: "gradle project sync failed. basic functionality (e.g. editing debugging) will not work properly 3.1" No sé por qué ha pasado esto. Esto es lo que tengo en el gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0-RC'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Si le doy a Try Again, me sale un mensaje que dice: "El archivo o directorio está dañado o es ilegible." y si estoy en el Main me sale un mensaje que dice "Kotlin is not configured". Por otro lado, si le doy a Build Project me sale el siguiente error:

```
"A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights."
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a el mensaje de error:

> "A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. Build was configured to
> prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository
> 'MavenRepo' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'

Al parecer usas una versión Canary de Android Studio, ve a el archivo `settings.gradle` en el proyecto y reemplaza:

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

con:

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
```

Comment: Hola. Perdona la tardanza. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, me ha servido.